# How to create same rnd numbers from standard cauchy distribution?

Tags: python, random

For a simulation i need an array of cauchy distributed random numbers. 
This can be easly done by the function

```
random.standard_cauchy(N)
```

Now i want to generate the exact same sequence of random numbers.

I tried

```
seed(42)
print(random.standard_cauchy(10), random.standard_cauchy(10))
```

, but i does not work. I am getting different sequences.

Is it possible to generate the same sequence of random numbers from the standard cauchy distribution?

Comment: I expect you need to set the seed value before each and every call to `random....`.

Answer (score 0):

it's because you need to "reset" the sequence.

that you have done is like `print(random.standard_cauchy(20))`

```
from numpy import random

random.seed(42)
print(random.standard_cauchy(10), random.standard_cauchy(10))
random.seed(42)
print(random.standard_cauchy(20))
```

**EDIT**

because with `print(random.standard_cauchy(10), random.standard_cauchy(10))`
you call one time `random.standard_cauchy(10)` and get the first ten numbers and then you call a second time `random.standard_cauchy(10)` and you get the second ten numbers.

So it's like `print(random.standard_cauchy(20))`

to print 2 series of the same numbers you need to set again the same value of the seed. When the seed value is fixed the sequence "restart".

```
from numpy import random :

random.seed(42)
print(random.standard_cauchy(10))
random.seed(42)
print(random.standard_cauchy(20))
```

you can do this in a for :

```
from numpy import random

for i in range (2):
    random.seed(42)
    print(random.standard_cauchy(10))
```

output :

```
[-3.59249748  0.42526319  1.00007012  2.05778128 -0.8652948   0.99503562
 -0.12646463  3.06767933 -3.22303808  0.64293825]
[-3.59249748  0.42526319  1.00007012  2.05778128 -0.8652948   0.99503562
 -0.12646463  3.06767933 -3.22303808  0.64293825]
```

Comment: Thx for your Help, i found my mistake. If you use ** from random import seed ** and rewrite random.seed(42) to seed(42) in your first example u will get different sequences. Weird. random.seed() and seed() should be the same function or?

Comment: it's the same function but not the same instance